# Dereference 2D Array Pointer In C

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, reference

I am pointing to the address of a 2D array, and I am confused as to how to dereference the pointer to free up the memory again.  (I don't use "->" or "*".  Is that wrong?)

My code:

```
double array[12][12];
//filled with numbers

double *arrayPtr; //pointer

arrayPtr = &array[0][0]; //pointing to address

multiply(arrayPtr, arrayPtr); //this works fine

//Do I need to do anything further to make sure my memory management is correct?  And if so, why?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the answer is no -- since you simply defined `array` (didn't use something like `malloc` to allocate it) you don't have to do anything to free it either. If it was local (defined inside a function) it'll be freed automatically when you exit the function. If you defined it outside any function, it's a global, so it'll exist the entire time the program runs. Either way, you don't have to d any explicit memory management.

Comment: Thank you very much for that.  Easy to understand and answered my question.  :D  

*I have to wait another few minutes to accept, but i will to ensure others can also see this solution

Answer (score 2):

```
double array[12][12];
```

You're declaring `array` on the stack. It's not dynamically allocated with the heap, so you don't "free up the memory".

```
double *arrayPtr; //pointer
arrayPtr = &array[0][0]; //pointing to address
```

If you want to point to the first element, this would suffice:

```
double* arrayPtr = array;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there a quite different between C and C++

In C to use memory management you shall use malloc/calloc/realloc and free. In c++ you will use new and delete.

In your code.

```
double array[12][12];
```

This is imply to allocate memory in stack. So the memory will be allocated to the scope of this program section so that it will be green when the scope of this variable end.

If you will to use free  you will need

```
 double **array;
 array = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double*));
 *array = (double*) malloc (24 * sizeof(double));

free (*array);
free (array);
```

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with this code... namely the casts are not only wrong but unnecessary and in this case illegal (I'm quite you cannot cast a pointer type to a floating type). Also, the syntax is wrong for the `free` part... the `()` are missing.

Comment: sorry, i not understand your comment, when you work pointer, and in C that;s is less restricted  that c++, you are allow to use () casting. Additionally, the casting imply interpret this memory section as the type cast you are doing. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: I know what casting is, the point is that you don't *need* to cast the result of `malloc`. In C, `void *` can be implicitly converted to any other pointer type without a cast. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) about why you should **not** cast the result of `malloc`.